# How do I simplify this complex query?

Tags: postgresql

The referred to table definitions are:

```
CREATE TABLE message
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    guild_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
);


CREATE TABLE d_user
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
);


CREATE TABLE vcsession
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    guild_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    duration INTEGER NOT NULL,
    began_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    last_active TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

The expected result set of this query should consist of a row for each user in the guild provided with columns for:

- `user_id`: The user id
- `message_count`: The number of messages sent by each user within an interval defined by two datetimes (this should be 0 if no messages were sent)
- `voice_time`: Sum of each voice session's duration last active within an interval defined by two datetimes (this should be 0 if no voice sessions were active)
- `active_days`: Days in which the user either sent a message or had an active voice session (this should be 0 if user wasn't active in the time interval provided)

This is the query I wrote:

```
select
    activity.user_id,
    message_count,
    voice_time,
    coalesce(active_days, 0) as active_days
from (
    select
         d_user.id as user_id,
         coalesce(messages.count, 0) as message_count,
         coalesce(vcsessions.duration, 0) as voice_time
    from d_user left join (
        select
            user_id,
            count(*) as "count"
        from message where (
            (guild_id = $1) and
            (created_at >= $2) and
            (created_at < $3)
        ) group by user_id
    ) as messages on messages.user_id = d_user.id left join (
        select
            user_id,
            sum(duration) as  "duration"
        from vcsession where (
            (guild_id = $1) and
            (last_active >= $2) and
            (last_active < $3)
        ) group by user_id
    ) as vcsessions on vcsessions.user_id = d_user.id
) as activity left join (
    select user_id, count(*) as active_days from (
        select * from (
            select
                user_id,
                (cast(extract(EPOCH from message.created_at) as int) - cast(extract(EPOCH from $2) as int)) / 86400 as day_offset
            from message where (
                (created_at >= $2) and
                (created_at < $3)
            ) group by user_id, day_offset
        ) as message_days union (
            select
                user_id,
                (cast(extract(EPOCH from vcsession.last_active) as int) - cast(extract(EPOCH from $2) as int)) / 86400 as day_offset
            from vcsession where (
                (last_active >= $2) and
                (last_active < $3)
            ) group by user_id, day_offset
        )
    ) as active_days group by user_id
) as active_days on active_days.user_id = activity.user_id
```

And this is what the result set looks like:

```
|user_id             |message_count       |voice_time          |active_days         |
|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|1                   |752                 |694                 |1                   |
|2                   |12                  |543                 |2                   |
|3                   |323                 |7163                |4                   |
|4                   |56                  |870                 |3                   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks reasonably readable to me.

Maybe you could pull the two subselects in the forst `FROM` clause into the main query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ((SELECT ...) AS messages
      LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT ...) AS vcsessions
     ) AS ...
   LEFT JOIN ...
```

could become

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT ...) AS messages
   LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT ...) AS vcsessions
   LEFT JOIN ...
```